# SSIS Delete redundant columns in pipeline

Tags: etl, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Anyone knows if it is still not possible to remove (not hide) unused or redundant columns from the pipeline / data stream? Well, I suppose there is a choice for either deleting the columns or just SELECTING relevant columns in the pipeline (and not at the destination end). How can this be achieved?

I notice there are ways around it but not exactly deleting. I dug around and seen responses up to year 2010 so not too sure if this was still the case.

Just saying...

Comment: In every transformation you can select what columns will be output to the pipeline and thus there won't be any unused or redundant column in the pipeline.

Comment: @Jayvee, OK Noted. Which component if I may ask?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to eliminate 'unused output column' warnings in SSIS jobs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266805/how-to-eliminate-unused-output-column-warnings-in-ssis-jobs)

Answer (score 1):

If right click on a source component and then edit you can select the columns in tab 'Columns' as in this picture:

[image]

On most of the components you can also select the output columns by right clicking, then 'Advance Editor' and then 'Input and Output Properties':

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope this still helps, I had to do the same for some of my ETL Packages that were using the Data Conversion component, basically the "problem" was that many metadata columns were being processed in the ETL Pipeline and we were only using the Data Converted Metadata columns in our destination OLE DB, not sure if this is the best workaround to remove the columns but I just added an UNION ALL component after the Data Conversion component and manually removed the "redundant" columns, in my case the columns that originally were coming from the source and that now are not needed because I have the already converted metadata fields.